# Java, quando uso CRTL+V aparece o sinal de interrogação na frente do texto?

Tags: java, utf-8

Fiz uma classe que vai buscar um texto em um arquivo `.TXT` que está salvo no formato UTF-8, e gravar no Clipboard para eu colar com CRTL+V em um campo de outro sistema. O problema é que quando eu uso o CRTL+V aparece um `?` antes do texto. Em alguns outros locais, se eu usar o CRTL+V ele cola certinho, mas no campo que eu preciso colar realmente, ele aparece essa `?` antes. Exemplo, se a o TXT conter "Olá Mundo!" e eu executar a classe e dar CRTL+V ele vai colar "`?Olá Mundo!`". Pesquisei bastante e no `notepad++` descobri que se eu colar algo lá e ir na opção "Codificar para ANSI" ele coloca esse `?` antes do texto, mas não entendo como resolver isso no meu código `JAVA`.

Classe:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Metodos {


    public void paste(String texto) {
        Clipboard board = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        ClipboardOwner selection = new StringSelection(texto);
        board.setContents((Transferable) selection, selection);

    }

    public String txt (String caminho){//"C:/Leia.txt"
   String linha = "";
      String ln = "";
    System.out.printf("\nConteúdo do arquivo texto:\n");
    try {
      File file = new File(caminho);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(
                   new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));

      //String content = readFile(caminho, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String str;

      while ((str = in.readLine()) != null){

        ln =str;

      }           
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n",
          e.getMessage());
    }
   return ln;

  }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Metodos m = new Metodos();

        String a = m.txt("D:/pasta/1.txt");
        m.paste(a);
       //para testar usar CRTL+V no Notepad++ 
    }


}
```

Comment: E em qual campo você precisa colar isso? Reproduzi aqui e não tive problemas, não apareceu nenhum  `?`.

Comment: O campo que preciso colar é dentro de um outro sistema da minha empresa, que não sei q linguagem foi desenvolvido.O problema é que em alguns campos aparece o ? e em outros não. O único lugar q dá para ver é no Notepas++. Se colocar apenas uma string no arquivo TXT, e ler ele, e contar quantas Strings tem, aparecerá 2, em função de ter esse ? na frente. Então resolví o problema excluindo a primeira String do texto antes de gravar no Clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi excluindo o primeiro caractere conforme abaixo:

```
String retornoDoMetodoPaste = retornoDoMetodoPaste.substring(1);
```